# How can I get a list of all my site's module and themes?

Tags: 9

I want to get the list of current modules and themes and modify them on Drupal 9, previously in Drupal 8,7 I used the following functions to get and save them but it seems they are depricated on Drupal 9.

```
 system_get_info(), _system_rebuild_module_data()
```

what is equivalent to these functions in Drupal 9 and how can get/update data about the module/themes in Drupal 9?

Comment: From the help center: How do I ask a good question?

We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips:
Search, and research

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: Wow Yusef, and now downvoting the answers. Really not nice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information can easily be found in the documentation, for example [`system_get_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_get_info).

Comment: @leymannx I could remember I down vote on answers. but the sound correct.
I apologize for that ( maybe someone seated behind my seat ). naughty colleagues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check the deprecation notice on [`system_get_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_get_info)

> #### Deprecated
>
> in drupal:8.8.0 and is removed from drupal:9.0.0. Use
>   `\Drupal::service('extension.list.$type')->getExtensionInfo()` or
>   `\Drupal::service('extension.list.$type')->getAllInstalledInfo()`
>   instead.

and the change record on [`_system_rebuild_module_data()` and co. are replaced by services to give you all available modules and themes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2709919)

> ```
> // If you want to just get all extensions without rebuilding.
> $module_list = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getList();
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The change records tell you all you need to know ...

https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal/published?keywords_description=system_get_info&to_branch=&version=&created_op=%3E%3D&created%5Bvalue%5D=&created%5Bmin%5D=&created%5Bmax%5D=

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know of drupal.org/list-changes/drupal, thanks for that gem! I was always just googling for the functions. 

Comment: @leymannx, there is a link on the project page https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal

Comment: @4k4 – Ah I've probably never been on that page, too! Bookmarked!